# nginx configuration for basic auth that allows lets encrypt to auto renew

Tags: ssl, nginx, configuration, basic-authentication, lets-encrypt

Currently, I can successfully install a [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) SSL certificate by leaving the below line in my nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I would like to have basic auth enabled on my website.  The below works fine to do so:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    auth_basic "Restricted Content";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
}
```

However, the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate must renew every month.  I can automate this renewal using curl.  However, Let's Encrypt has a callback along a route that contains a route with the prefix:

```
/.well-known/acme-challenge/
```

but now, I need to add an exception for the above route prefix:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    auth_basic off;
}
```

I have tried many variations of the above, but none seem to be working.  I cannot get the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate to install with the above configuration.  I even determined that if I take off the basic auth (by deleting the two lines that begin with auth_basic), the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate won't install if all I have is the below:

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions so the callback route will run while basic auth is enabled.  I'd also be interested in learning why I can't install Let's Encrypt with the config as shown above where basic auth isn't even enabled.  Thanks in advance.

Additional error logs:

```
/var/log/nginx# cat cert.dev.farm-error.log.1
2016/03/18 13:12:26 [error] 12336#12336: *1 open() "/home/forge/cert.dev.farm/public/.well-known/acme-challenge/jGhldzH8cV3d666a44nRy-Gzf98m1u2qUbkWnNv0aMI" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.133.109.36, server: cert.dev.farm, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/jGhldzH8cV3d666a44nRy-Gzf98m1u2qUbkWnNv0aMI HTTP/1.1", host: "cert.dev.farm"
2016/03/18 13:17:09 [error] 13202#13202: *1 open() "/home/forge/cert.dev.farm/.well-known/acme-challenge/k9jsDB_mkvU5UzvL-B7hd3iA90ZTq61OaDNixoeRQuQ" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.133.109.36, server: cert.dev.farm, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/k9jsDB_mkvU5UzvL-B7hd3iA90ZTq61OaDNixoeRQuQ HTTP/1.1", host: "cert.dev.farm"
2016/03/18 13:17:09 [error] 13202#13202: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /home/forge/cert.dev.farm/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 66.133.109.36, server: cert.dev.farm, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/k9jsDB_mkvU5UzvL-B7hd3iA90ZTq61OaDNixoeRQuQ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "cert.dev.farm"
2016/03/18 13:23:48 [error] 14522#14522: *1 open() "/home/forge/cert.dev.farm/public/.well-known/acme-challenge/5ZBXFn23tOUPcQFNrI3DqUE-l9x3rmdiOkYwabDl-jk" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 66.133.109.36, server: cert.dev.farm, request: "GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/5ZBXFn23tOUPcQFNrI3DqUE-l9x3rmdiOkYwabDl-jk HTTP/1.1", host: "cert.dev.farm"
```

Comment: What is your nginx root path, are you seeing that in the error log, and does that match the webroot you passed to letsencrypt?

Comment: @kyl191 I've added some more error logs above.  Let me know if that's what you're looking for or not.  The root path is /home/forge - I think the problem is simply I need to tweak the below:

location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    auth_basic off;
}

I'm wondering if the below is better?

    location /.well-known/ {
        auth_basic off;
        index nothing_will_match;
        autoindex on;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the renew command of the cli client:

```
➜ sudo letsencrypt renew

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Processing /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.com.conf
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The following certs are not due for renewal yet:
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem (skipped)
No renewals were attempted.
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably miss a document root being set for the `/.well-known/acme-challenge` location block.

```
location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /path/to/your/public/directory;
    try_files $uri;
    auth_basic off;
}

location / {
    ...
}
```

You said you can automate it using CURL, did you have a look at the [list of available clients](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/list-of-client-implementations/2103)?

Comment: Yes, you need to point the document root to correspond to the webroot specified in the original command using the -w parameter.